# Code Stopped Working Randomly After Changing Pages with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation, seleniumbase

So, i make a automation to log into podcaster.spotify.com, but for some reason the code sometimes stop after it click the spotify_button

Sometimes the code work and click the next button, but more often than not it just stuck there and not doing anything.

What i've Tried to solve that :

1. Implementing time.sleep
2. Implementing wait_for_element_clickable
3. Implementing WebDriverWait

```
from seleniumbase import Driver
from seleniumbase import page_actions

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from time import sleep
import pickle

# Setup
driver = Driver(headless=False, uc=True)

driver.get('https://podcasters.spotify.com/pod/dashboard/home/')
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))

for cookie in cookies :
    cookie['domain'] = '.spotify.com'
    try :
        driver.add_cookie(cookie)
    except :
        pass

page_actions.wait_for_element_clickable(driver,'//button[@data-encore-id="buttonPrimary"]', By.XPATH, 10)
spotify_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-encore-id="buttonPrimary"]')
spotify_button.click()

# CODE SOMETIMES STOPS HERE

sleep(1)
page_actions.wait_for_element_clickable(driver, '//button[@data-testid="auth-accept"]', By.XPATH, 3)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[@data-testid="auth-accept"]').click()
```

Comment: Try using [playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro) instead. It doesn't require a webdriver, and is a much newer python library. It works with chrome, msedge, firefox, webkit, and chromium.